# Error while browsing application in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am using asp.net 2.0 with C#.
I have deployed my application on IIS and while browsing it I am receiving below error:

Could not write to output file 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7179d944\dd7c82ae\App_Web_adlogin.aspx.cdcab7d2.rqcxmj0e.dll'

Please suggest us how can I remove this error, this is urgent.

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: Is this in a production environment?

Comment: Yes it is production environment & I have login as admin.

Answer (score 0):

The network service account, or other account if you have changed your application pool user, needs to have access to the temp folder mentioned in the error. You can normally do this most easily by running the command below from command prompt.

aspnet_regiis.exe /ga actual_acount_here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perform a disk check and clean up the whole c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ folder. It happens from time to time on IIS6.